# Is there a way to reverse the amplitude_to_db back to a clear audio?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, librosa, spectrogram

We are trying to denoise audio using spectrograms, we reduce the amplitude of frequencies found in a specific portion of the spectrogram and once the noise reduction is done, we want the data of the spectrogram to be converted back to its audio format.

We create a spectrogram using this:

```
Audio = librosa.stft(data)
spec = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(Audio), ref=np.max)
```

and we try to bring it back to audio using this:

```
S = librosa.db_to_amplitude(spec)
audio = librosa.istft(S)
```

we preview the audio using this:

```
IPython.display.Audio(data=audio, rate=22000)
```

we have discovered that the problem isn't with our method to denoise the audio but maybe on how we have implemented the modules of Librosa. We tried to convert audio to spectrogram and back to audio without the denoising module that we have created, yet we are still not achieving a clear translation from spectrogram to audio using the `librosa.db_to_amplitude` module.

- file formats used: .flac input, .wav output
- original audio: [Original Audio](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lgAE3UapGiwr9DHOXPwdgm9BmA-ebNHm/view?usp=sharing)
- audio converted to spectrogram and back to audio without any denoising done: [Processed Audio](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kgyIgRvzNs7v9lzF90sm2VEaONz11mM1/view?usp=sharing)

> Thank you very much!

Comment: simply `istft(stft(data))` would work. audio data samples can be positive or negative  but you discard this information with `np.abs`. if you do `db_to_amplitude(amplitude_to_db([-1]))` you lose the sign as well.

Comment: When you discard the phase (using the abs), then you need to re-estimate it, which is a tricky process and hard to do without artifacts. Griffin-Lim is one basic method, available in librosa